# How to repair Eclipse broken Android SDK libraries?

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, adt, libraries

While downloading the libraries these 3 libraries got broken for unknown reasons. How can I fix these. I tried deleting them, but when I restarted the SDK manager these won't come up again for downloading option.

I've downloaded whole libraries of 37GB. And I don't want to download all that again.

IDE : Eclipse Juno

Architecture : 64bit

Waiting for all your helps soon.

Thanks in Advance.

[Find the attached image.](http://postimg.org/image/44qechtkz/)

PS:I don't know if this has been answered or not, but I tried my best to find the solution, but ALAS!!!!

Comment: Select them > Delete Them > Install again

Comment: What part needs to be edited.Please specify @Rajesh

Comment: I deleted them, but it won't show again for download option. @Ajeet

Comment: Did you try packages>Reload ?

Comment: I tried them right now, but nothing new comes up. @Ajeet

Comment: Your Code need to be edited...

Comment: Did you set HTTP proxy in Tools>option ..may be you are missing this ..may be

Comment: Have you read my question properly? I am not asking anything about any codes. I want to repair the API libraries that has been broken.How am I supposed to edit Google Inc. API Libraries Codes..?? @Rajesh

Comment: [link](http://postimg.org/image/u17xrgcdh/) What am I supposed to do here? @Ajeet

Comment: go with android studio, it is way better if you only want to develop android apps

Comment: android studio slows down my laptop beyond imagination... Can you specify the RECOMMEND specification for the android studio? @PankajNimgade

Comment: @PankajNimgade It's not the question, but yes you should also try android studio. Http proxy are simply settings you to connect internet but i think its not the problem here as you were able to install it before.

Comment: You can reinstall ADT bundle ..do Help-->Install New Software-->What is already installed?  unistall ...install again..

Comment: @NrusinghPrasadAcharya, SOrry amn I do agree with you, Android Studio takes a lot of memory having a bigger system drive might give you more space but still you would require (Intel i5 + or AMD A8

Comment: That means I've to download ALL the libraries (37GB) once more??? @Ajeet

Comment: @NrusinghPrasadAcharya No sir, Installing all libraries is not necessary. Just install preselected library when you opened your SDKmanager.exe first time. Also you don't need to download those library again. They all are saved in SDK folder. After uninstalling go to your SDK folder and run SDK manager i guess

Comment: That is the problem. Those deleted APIs won't show for re-downloading. @Ajeet